# Return two dimensional array from jquery post

Tags: jquery

I am racking my brain, I need to send via jquery post a searching value for fulltext search in database and then display it in a div element. I need to search value in Category table and in SubCategory table. I can't figure it out, I think the best would be if I post it twice (first to search in category and second to search in subcategy). The function search_fulltext returns two-dimensional array.

I was thinking of something like this (I know it does not work but just want to demonstrate how I want it work, I don't know how to cope with two-dimensional arrays)

// SCRIPT

```
function onclick_search_button(searching_value, at)
{
// first post to search in categories
$.post("search.php", {what:searching_value, where: at}, function(data,status){
 // echo list of found results in CATEGORIES
 var found_items = eval(data);
 for(var i=0; i<found_items.length; i++)
  {
   $result = "Found in category: " + found_items[i]["cat_name"] + "and ID is: " + items[i]["cat_id"] + "</br>"; 
   $("#final_div_results").append($result);
  }

// second post to search in subcategories
$.post("search.php", {what:searching_value}, function(data,status){
 // echo list of found results in CATEGORIES
 var found_items = eval(data);
 for(var i=0; i<found_items.length; i++)
  {
   $result = "Found in category: " + found_items[i]["sub_cat_name"] + "and ID is: " + items[i]["cat_id"] + "</br>"; 
   $("#final_div_results").append($result);
  }
}
```

// SEARCH.PHP FILE

```
<?
$inst = new DbQuery();

$what = $_POST["what"];
$where = $_POST["at"];

$result = $inst->search_fulltext($what, $where);
// BUT SEARCH_FULLTEXT RETURNS TWO-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY SO I GUESS I CANNOT USE THE FOLLOWING
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

// HTML DIV

```
<div id="final_div_results">These are the results</div>
```

Comment: `json_encode` works just fine with 2d arrays. P.S. *DON'T* do `eval(data)`!  Add `'json'` as the 4th param in your `$.post`:  `$.post("search.php", {your: data}, function(found_items){}, 'json');`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a json-encoded 2-dimensional array.  Then you can access the returned data like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'search.php',
  data: {what:searching_value},
  success: function(data){
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
       $result = "Found in category: " + data[i].sub_cat_name + "and ID is: " + data[i].cat_id + "</br>"; 
       $("#final_div_results").append($result);
     }
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```